# What role did Elizabeth II play in actions of the British Empire during her reign?

Tags: united-kingdom, british-empire, monarchy, decolonization

Much of the critical commentary on Elizabeth II's legacy following her death has concerned actions of the British state in its colonies during her reign. An historically significant number of these territories gained their independence during this period despite significant efforts by the British state, which at times such as during the Mau Mau rebellion in Kenya have been criticised as oppressive if not criminal.

Defenders of this legacy point to the political neutrality expected of the monarchy and the limited ability of the Crown to exercise even powers it notionally possesses without destabilising the constitutional regime that keeps the monarchy in place.

Did Elizabeth make any historically important interventions during her reign that influenced these events politically or diplomatically? If not, or as well as these, are there interventions she declined to make that might have influenced the events some now associate with her legacy? And were there contemporaneous public calls for her to act one way or the other?

Comment: One dramatic intervention by Elizabeth II was in women's rights in KSA: she was an army truck driver during WW2, so when the Saudi monarch visited her, [she got behind the wheel and drove him around](https://www.wearethemighty.com/articles/this-female-wwii-veteran-terrified-a-saudi-king-while-driving-him-around/) the Scottish mountains, convincing him that women can drive.

Comment: I've seen folks online talking about [Queen's/Kings Consent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Consent) as a reason why she's complicit in every action any UK government undertook during her long reign. Seems to me she didn't in reality have a veto through that process, and any suggestions she made the government was perfectly free to ignore, so that's not anywhere near enough power to constitute responsibility. However, I'm not the expert on UK legislative arcana that some of our other users here are.

Comment: I'm far from knowledgable in this. Maybe someone could comment on [this book](https://academic.oup.com/book/2592) -  [reviewed here](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/queen-elizabeth-II/10539479/Only-the-Queen-understands-the-true-value-of-the-Commonwealth.html) that the Queen, as Head of the Commonwealth, was not bound to neutrality and actually exercised political influence in matters of British relations with its former colonies.

Comment: The title question seems rather broad and doesn't accurately reflect the main body. Perhaps re-phrase to get closer to the third para.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I've edited to be more specific about active involvement, not sure if that covers your concern about breadth? If not I'm open to suggestions...

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: During a controversy on Sikh turbans in Royal Canadian Legion, [the Queen chatted](https://www.nriinternet.com/NRI_Defense/CANADA/Indian_Ex_Service_Men/J/Col_Pritam_Johal/2_Sikhs_and_Turban.htm) with Sikh Canadian service members: "The Queen at a Royal Tea Party given in Her honour by the Government of British Columbia, at Victoria on August 20, 1994, chatted with five Indian Army turbaned invited Veteran guests - namely {names omitted> and inquired if they were denied admittance to Canadian Legion buildings on Remembrance Day in 1993?" The controversy ended then and there.

Comment: The late queen couldn't make historically important interventions, as she constitutionally reigned but not ruled.

Comment: @Jos lots of important interventions in history are not exercises of executive power. There's a reason I didn't ask this question on the Law SE.